# How to add text decoration to an image?

Tags: css, image, icons, underline

I'm having a bit of a rough time. I've created some icons to go beside a few links. The links have the "underline" text decoration effect being applied to them on hover. I added the icons, and it fits in perfectly, it's just that the icons are not underlined when the anchor tag is hovered over. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
                    <a class="link" href="#"> 
                        <img src="images/home.png" alt="" id="home" class="icon"/>
                        home
                    </a>
                    <a class="link" href="about/">
                        <img src="images/about.png" alt="" id="about" class="icon"/>
                        About
                    </a>
                    <a class="link" href="contact/">
                        <img src="images/contact.png" alt="" id="contact" class="icon"/>
                        Contact
                    </a>
                    <a class="link" href="work/">
                        <img src="images/work.png" alt="" id="work" class="icon"/>
                        Work
                    </a>
```

CSS

```
#home {

    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

}

#about { 

    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

}

#contact {

    width: 19px;
    height: 15px;

}

#work {

    width: 16px;
    height: 15px;

}

.link {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: arial;

}

.link:link {

    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.link:visited {

    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.link:active {

    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.link:hover {

    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;

}
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try something like this :: (you cant underline a `img` with `text-decoration` property)

```
a{
margin-left:30px;
font-size:18px;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover { 
border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
```

EXAMPLE :: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g7Ujk/)**

Comment: I should have added, I tried this also. The problems here being that I cannot use the border property, because I'm using the line-height property to align my links in the navigation bar, thus the border shows up at the bottom of my navigation bar, not under the words. Now, I could set a margin-top property instead of line-height, but it would be imperfectly aligned, something I don't want. The second problem is that when I do use the margin-top method instead of the line-height method, the space between the border and the text is too wide, even though no height is defined. 

Other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

All right, I figured it out. I did end up using the border method. By defining the height of the "link" class, I could increase or decrease the distance from the text and icon to the bottom border.

For anyone else with this issue, the fixed code was...

HTML

```
        <div class="navbar">
                    <a class="link" href="#"> 
                        <img src="images/home.png" alt="" id="home" class="icon"/>
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <a class="link" href="about/">
                        <img src="images/about.png" alt="" id="about" class="icon"/>
                        About
                    </a>
                    <a class="link" href="contact/">
                        <img src="images/contact.png" alt="" id="contact" class="icon"/>
                        Contact
                    </a>
                    <a class="link" href="work/">
                        <img src="images/work.png" alt="" id="work" class="icon"/>
                        Work
                    </a>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#home {

    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

}

#about { 

    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

}

#contact {

    width: 19px;
    height: 15px;

}

#work {

    width: 16px;
    height: 15px;

}

.link {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 18px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: arial;

}

.link:link {

    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.link:visited {

    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.link:active {

    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.link:hover {

    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;

}
```